# 16 Hour Marine Atlantic Ferry Trip with no Cabin

Tags: canada, ferries, sleeping, nova-scotia, newfoundland

[Marine Atlantic](https://www.marineatlantic.ca/sailing-information/sailing-routes) operates 16 hour overnight ferry trips from North Sydney, Nova Scotia to Argentia, Newfoundland on the MV *Atlantic Vision*. As I understand it, you can bring a car, but you cannot access your car during the trip.

Purchasing a cabin is optional (and expensive) so I'd rather not. Are there relatively quiet places where people won't bother you if you want to catch some sleep overnight, or do you really need to book a cabin if you want to sleep at all?

Comment: Is this travel during or after COVID 19? As European ferries have temporary measures because of which cabins have to be used.

Comment: Car access at sea is almost always made impossible for safety and security reasons.   It's far easier just to lock the passengers out than to let them in safely.  They're also very much not designed for evacuation in case of emergency, just when vehicles may shift around.

Comment: @Willeke I'm currently thinking about late summer '21, so hopefully not too much COVID? I don't see anything to that effect on their website though

Answer (score 3):

Many similar services allow/require you to book an "aircraft-style sleeper seat" or similar if you're not booking a cabin berth.  On some it's included in the price.  Those seats tend to be in rooms that are supposed to be quiet overnight, but with many people in are probably lighter and noisier than you might like, like an oversize aeroplane cabin but with a bit more space to move around. An eye mask and good earplugs might be enough.  They don't seem to list it on the website, but the picture on [the amenities and facilities page](https://www.marineatlantic.ca/onboard-experience/amenities-facilities) shows that sort of lounge, but with a bar to one side - the question is how late it's open and how noisy it gets (they may serve quietly).

I have, on a shorter, rather empty overnight crossing, slept on a sofa in the bar area (well away from where they were serving.  I wasn't alone.  In fact I was in the minority by sleeping just in my clothes with my head on my bag - pyjamas and blankets or even sleeping bags were common.  I did make sure to have an eye mask and earplugs.